# How to add a style on a condition in tailwind css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I am making a Side Nav in React using tailwind css I have to add border-red color when a particular link is selected. So I am using this approach But this is not working Can anyone help me here

```
<li className={"flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-5 transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 border-l-4 border-white" + (window.location.pathname === '/' ? 'border-red-200' : '')}>
              <NavLink to={"/"}>
                <div className="sidebar">
                  <div className="float-left">
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      className="h-8 w-6 text-red-400"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                    >
                      <path
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6"
                      />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                  <span className="text-2xl float-right pl-5">
                    Home
                  </span>
                </div>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
```

Comment: I am not sure about the condition. See https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string . Or, try with a space : `' border-red-200'`

Comment: Thanks its working but now when I change to another link the border color is still there it is not getting updated on its own. I have 5 other list elements with the sane condition. It is working fine when I refresh the page.

Comment: Try [activeClassName](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string) or [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook.

Answer (score 45):

Use template literals, or use npm library [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).

- Using template literals

```js
<... className={`flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-5 transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 border-l-4 border-white ${window.location.pathname === '/' ? 'border-red-200' : ''}`}>
```

- Using **classnames** library

```js
import classNames from 'classnames';

<... className={classNames('flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-5 transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 border-l-4 border-white',
    { 
        'border-red-200': window.location.pathname === '/' 
    }
)}>
```

Comment: Might be useful to mention that the conditional can also happen outside of the template literal like `const borderColor = window.location.pathname === '/' ? 'border-red-200' : ''` and then `<... className={`flex ${borderColor }`}`. Tailwind can still detect the class name: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

Answer (score 11):

```
className={yourItem === value ? 'your-class' : 'or-default-to'}
```

`
/* This applys classes if your set condition is true on not. Example below*/

```
className={active === value ? 'text-green' : 'text-white'}

class={active === value ? 'text-green' : 'text-white'}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using classnames library is for me the cleanest way with multiple conditions:

import cx from 'classnames';

```
const classes = cx(
        'flex items-center justify-center', // classes that should be used in any case
        size === 'small' && 'h-10 text-lg px-2.5',
        size === 'medium' && 'h-12 text-lg px-4',
        variant === 'primary text-primary`,
        variant === 'secondary text-secondary`,
        fullWidth && 'w-full',
        className // classname passed from props
    );
```

But in you case string interpolation should be enough

```
`flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-5 transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 border-l-4 border-white ${window.location.pathname === '/' ? 'border-red-200' : ''}`
```

Answer (score 1):

write your classname like this in li tag:

```
className={`flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-5 transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 border-l-4 border-white ${window.location.pathname === '/' ? 'border-red-200' : ''}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use clsx npm package is most used in industries
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

example :
className={clsx(
condition
? 'bg-black text-white'
: 'border-transparent, 'another css')}

Answer (score -1):

you can have a state `isSelected` that changes `onClick`. then create a function that accepts the state and then use it inside `className`:

```js
// clsn function module:
export default function clsn(...args) {
    return args.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}
```

```js
import clsn from ".../module_path";

const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
const clickHandler = () => {
    setActive(!active);
    };
return (
...
    <NavLink
        className={
            clsn("inline-flex",
            active && "bg-red");
        }
        onClick={clickHandler}
    >
)
```

this way `inline-flex` styles applies always, and `bg-red` styles applies only when `active` is `true`.

Answer (score -3):

For NavLink component you can use activeStyle prop to apply styles when the link is active.

```
<NavLink
   to="/"
   activeStyle={{
   border-bottom: "2px solid red"; 
      }}
    >
     Link Name
</NavLink>
```